# Sensors Allocation using Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am working on an optimization problem, I need to find the minimum number of sensors between objects.

I have 7 objects and need to find the minimum number of sensor to be able to distinguish those objects. I have a sensor to detect color, a sensor to detect the dimension and a sensor to detect the weight (very simple and dumb sensor that only replies with a yes or no). Each object is unique and I want to use the minimum number of sensors to be able to identify each object. I want to use a combination of all sensor.

How would I use an lp solver to help? What will my variables be and what will my constraints be?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Does each object have three attributes? Color, Weight and dimension. And by unique you mean all three cannot be the same for two objects. Can you elaborate a little on the weight sensor? Is a weight guess input to the sensor?

Comment: In addition to what @RamNarasimhan said above, it is not clear in your formulation wether all the sensors or just the 'dimension' one are binary. If all sensors can only answer 'yes' or 'no', you obviously need 3 sensors to distinguish the 7 objects from a basic combinatory argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like a machine learning problem than an optimisation problem. What you're really asking is what features you need to compute to make an accurate classification. This all depends on your objects -- can you distinguish all of them just by color? Or do you need additional attributes?

If you have those attributes for all the objects, you could build a decision tree (e.g. using [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)) and look at that. The attributes used in the tree would give you an idea of what sensors you need. You should get a pretty good idea just looking at the data though.

If the position of the sensors is an issue as well, it might be worth having a look at optimisation. For what you've described, there's no need though.